# Can ExpressionEngine entries support one-to-many relationships?

Tags: expressionengine

I'm building a cookery website for a client, who's decided to use ExpressionEngine (not my choice, I did try and opt for something different). One aspect of the website is the ability for logged-in members to add recipes.

So far, I've create a channel for recipes and a channel for ingredients. I've then extended the Member module and create a SAEF with the Safecracker module so logged-in users can add a recipe entry. However, where I'm stuck is trying to create a one-to-many relationships, where a recipe can have many ingredients, and an ingredient can belong to many recipes.

Does ExpressionEngine support this out of the box and I'm missing it? Or does I have to do some hacking? Or am I going over this in completely the wrong manner?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a 3rd party commercial add-on called [Playa](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa) ("Playa" being a playful take on 1-to-many relationships). It's from [Pixel & Tonic](http://pixelandtonic.com/) and will do exactly what you need. Their add-ons and support are top-notch.

That way your client will have the feature they need with an optimal interface on both the back end control panel and within the front-end safecracker form. No hacking needed for this and maintainability is much more solid over time as opposed to hacking at EE's core.

Comment: Hmm, was after something free or open source if I'm honest. I'm not in control of the budget on this site.

Comment: You could try "this relationship fieldtype":http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/multi-relationships which is cheaper. But Playa is worth every penny.

Comment: I'd suggest biting the bullet and paying for Playa, just as Erik and Derek have done. Playa is so robust and full of great templating features that it's worth the price. The time that you'll save on implementation and client support is worth way more than $75.